# Simple click listview and start new activity-(Impossible)

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

Ok,now I cant figure this one, that should be really simple.I have read so many StackOverflow questions but still nothing. 
I just want to start a new activity after the user clicks on the list.So simple!

```
public class Lista2Activity extends ListActivity {
    TextView selection;
    String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet",
                    "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi", "vel",
                    "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis",
                    "etiam", "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante",
                    "porttitor", "sodales", "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
        selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(parent, v, position, id);

        selection.setText(items[position]);
        Intent hash=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),another.class);
        startActivity(hash);

    }
}
```

It is failing on the `Intent` part.

Comment: Is there an exception? What kind of exception?

Comment: Its very easy. what is the problem you are facing. force close? if yes, please post the log cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**

```
Intent hash=new Intent(YourActivity.this,another.class);
    startActivity(hash);
```

**Instead of**

```
 Intent hash=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),another.class);
    startActivity(hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain how exactly it is "failing". However, one of the most common things people forget when trying to start a new activity is defining the activity in their AndroidManifest.xml file. For each Activity-class add the an `<activity/>` node as a child of the `<application/>` node:

```
<application ...>
...
    <activity android:name="fully.qualified.name.of.another.Class"/>
...
</application>
```

...where `android:name`contains the fully qualified name of your activity class.